# adding a column to a table with different parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to enter 2 tables into one output my problem is that the parameter is pulling from 2 different columns. I need to be able to show what was completed and the work ordered for a months period. I do not get any errors as the script is written but after 3 hours I stopped it from running.

If I change the join on the `@Ordered` to `iAuditID` from `EffectiveDate` it takes a few seconds to run, but it does not pull the correct information then. I only need the count of ordered audits to be correct and in the `@data` table and correct. Work may have been ordered a few months before it was completed, therefore I need to be able see how much work is coming in each month and what is being completed.

I am using SQL 2008.

```
DECLARE 
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@iClientID int,
@iServiceLevelID int

SET @StartDate = '1-1-13'
SET @EndDate = '12-30-13'

SET DATEFIRST 7

DECLARE @TB1 TABLE (EffectiveDate datetime, 
                    iAuditID int,
                    iClientID int, 
                    iServiceLevelID int)
INSERT INTO @TB1

SELECT dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, a.dtClosedDate),0) AS EffectiveDate, 
       a.iAuditID, a.iClientID, a.iServiceLevelID               
FROM vwtblAudit a    
WHERE (a.dtClosedDate >= @StartDate) 
AND (a.dtClosedDate <= @EndDate) 
AND (a.iClientID = @iClientID OR @iClientID is null) 
AND (a.iServiceLevelID = @iServiceLevelID or @iServiceLevelID is null)
GROUP BY dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, a.dtClosedDate),0),
    a.iClientID, a.iAuditID, a.iServiceLevelID

DECLARE @Ordered TABLE (EffectiveDate datetime, 
                        iAuditID int, 
                        iClientID int, 
                        iServiceLevelID int, 
                        dtOpenDate int)

INSERT INTO @Ordered    
SELECT dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, a.dtOpenDate),0) AS EffectiveDate, 
    a.iAuditID, a.iClientID, a.iServiceLevelID,
    Count(a.dtOpenDate) as Ordered
FROM tblAudit a
WHERE (a.dtOpenDate >= @StartDate) 
AND (a.dtOpenDate <= @EndDate) 
AND (a.iClientID = @iClientID OR @iClientID is null) 
AND (a.iServiceLevelID = @iServiceLevelID or @iServiceLevelID is null)
GROUP BY dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, a.dtOpenDate),0), 
    a.iClientID, a.iServiceLevelID, a.iAuditID
order by iClientID, EffectiveDate   

DECLARE @DATA table(iclientID int, 
                    sClientCode varchar(8), 
                    sClientName varchar(50), 
                    iServiceLevelID int,
                    sServiceLevelName varchar(50), 
                    EffectiveDate datetime, 
                    iAuditCount int, 
                    Completed int)

SELECT tblClient.iclientID, tblClient.sClientCode, tblClient.sClientName, 
       tblServiceLevel.iServiceLevelID, 
       TB1.EffectiveDate, COUNT(*) AS iAuditCount, 
       COUNT(Ordered.dtOpenDate) as Ordered    
FROM    @TB1 TB1 INNER JOIN
    tblClient ON TB1.iClientID = tblClient.iClientID INNER JOIN
    tblServiceLevel ON TB1.iServiceLevelID = tblServiceLevel.iServiceLevelID
    join @Ordered Ordered on TB1.EffectiveDate=Ordered.EffectiveDate
GROUP BY tblClient.iClientID, TB1.iServiceLevelID, tblclient.sClientCode, 
         tblClient.sClientName, tblServiceLevel.iServiceLevelID, 
         tblServiceLevel.sServiceLevelName, TB1.EffectiveDate 
return

SET DATEFIRST 7
```

Every a from the `@data` worked like it should, but I was ask to add the work coming in, so I added `@ordered` table to bring in the correct information. The data is still correct except for the ordered column. See sample below:

```
clientID  ClientCode ClientName iServiceLevelID EffectiveDate iAuditCount Ordered
 0001         1001      Sample         1            Jan 2014       104        19(this number should be 134)
```

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do.  It is helpful to include sample data and desired results.

Comment: If your question is about the performance can you please show all indexes and indicate how many rows exits.  If it is about the data returned please show sample data from the tables involved, explain what you expect to see *and why* you expect to see those values.

Comment: `19(this number should be 134)` Please explain why it should "134". Include enough data so that we can understand why "19" is wrong. As far as we know, "19" is correct.

Comment: when i run the ordered table by itself i get 134. the TB1 table uses the parameters for a finished product but I need to use the open date for the ordered table with my parameters.